# batch File : Output redirection post triggering installer

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file and it triggers an oracle installer.

1. Issue is installer gets triggered but the log does not get generated(%log2% is C:\1.txt).

> setup -silent -responseFile f:\Patch_Scripts\SESInstll.rsp >%log2%

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts:
You have the -silent option for the setup... what does this do and is this hiding all output?
Did you intend to append to a file... with your single redirect you are effectively creating a new file (probably not your problem, but figured I'd mention it).

Can you provide your batch file; might help with the debugging.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. -silent is for the installer to run without prompting to enter a username and password which is optional, this was suggested by oracle. Second, the redirect file already exists i.e. %log2% is set to F:\~log.txt since it is an official doc, i can't supply the full file What i also just saw is that my bat file, when it runs the setup, pops another cmd (temporary for few secs) that triggers the installer, hence there are 3 windows visible (initial batch cmd, temp cmd and installer GUI) i guess hence the redirect does not work as it is logging the empty second temporary pop up! hufff